# What is the proper way to execute a complex shell command within C++?

Tags: c++, linux, shell

I have been using code similar to this example to get the results to Linux shell commands from within C++.  It seems to work great with basic commands.  However, when I try to run it with the command in the example I get the shell error: syntax error near unexpected token `('

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    std::string cmdString = "cat <(grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat) <(sleep 1 && grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat) | "
                            "awk -v RS=\"\" '{print ($13-$2+$15-$4)*100/($13-$2+$15-$4+$16-$5) }' 2>&1";

    std::string result, file;
    FILE *stream;

    std::cout << "cmdString = " << cmdString << std::endl;

    stream = popen(cmdString.c_str(), "r");

    char buffer[256];
    if(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stream) != NULL) {
        file = buffer;
        result += file.substr(0, file.size() - 1);
    }
    pclose(stream);

    std::cout << "result = " << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?  Do I need to reformat the string somehow?

Comment: "Am I doing something wrong?" - I'd say 'yes', based on the simple fact that you are calling out to the shell. That alone sets off huge alarm bells and raises many red flags. At the *very least* something like that needs to be done *very* carefully - checking input args carefully, making sure the environment is sane, checking for errors, making sure you run the executable you really intend, etc etc.

Comment: Does this command work in the shell itself?

Comment: start reading here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html

Comment: Don't expect your command to be executed by `bash`. POSIX mandates that the shell used in `popen` is `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @Drop depends on what you call "the" shel...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `bash`-specific constructs in your command line. POSIX mandates that the argument of `popen` is passed to `bin/sh`, not user's current shell.

To fix the problem you can do one of the following:

1. Rewrite the commands to be `/bin/sh`-compliant.
2. Explicitly use `bash` in your command line:
   `std::string cmdString = "bash -c \".....\"";`
3. Drop the shell altogether and implement the pipeline yourself.